# is there a size limit when using the file tag in html?

Tags: html, file, file-upload

is there any limit when using the file attribute in html to upload file (then later move_uploaded_file() in php to transfer them)? obviously ridicoulous file sizes wouldnt work, but iv heard somewhere that there is a 2mb size limit. is this true?

Comment: No, that's not true. File upload max sizes are general set by the server. 2M is nothing--tons of Youtube videos far exceed that.

Comment: oh obviously, for youtube i wasnt expecting they just used the file tag, I assumed they had their own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes.
>   Though PHP presents a very versatile and user friendly interface for handling file uploads, the default installation is not geared for working with files in excess of 2 Mega Bytes.

But you can change it using

> php.ini

file upto 25MB

You can call the phpinfo() function to find the location of your php.ini file, it will also tell you the current values for the following settings that we need to modify

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize

Answer (score 2):

File upload size is not generally restricted on the client side, and even if it is there are some clients who will ignore this. It is the server side implementation that governs file size restrictions in the majority of cases. As such in the case of php this is governed by the `post_max_size` value of the `php.ini` file. So there is technically no limit ( as you can set this to be any value ).

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is true in php 2M is the deafult file upload limit if u wnat to extend it than 
go to php.ini file and change

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

To

```
upload_max_filesize = nM
```

n can be your required limit number.

**Reference: [core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)**